# Wht repeated customer count query not working in nestjs with postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a `nestjs` application with `typORM`, `postgres`. I have a database where i have orders, customers tables. There is a relationship many-to-one between orders and customer developed by typeORM entity. So, automatically, `customerId` field has been created in the `orders` table.

Here is my order entity

```
import {
  BaseEntity,
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  Index,
  JoinColumn,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Customer } from './customer.entity';
import { OrderProduct } from './order-product.entity';
import { OrderStatus } from 'src/modules/order/enums/order-setatus.enum';

@Entity('orders')
export class Order extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column({
    length: 500,
  })
  description: string;

  @Column({
    nullable: true,
  })
  quantity: number;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
  })
  amount: number;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
  })
  paymentMethod: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Customer, (customer) => customer.orders)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'customerId' })
  @Index()
  customer: Customer;

  @OneToMany(() => OrderProduct, (orderProduct) => orderProduct.order, {
    cascade: ['insert', 'update', 'remove'],
  })
  @JoinTable()
  products: Array<OrderProduct>;

  @Column({
    nullable: true,
  })
  totalWeight: string;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
    type: 'enum',
    enum: OrderStatus,
    default: OrderStatus.PENDING,
  })
  status: OrderStatus;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
    default: new Date(),
  })
  orderDate: Date;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

I have total 36 customers and i manually counted that there are total 5 customers who have more than 1 order.

Now, i want to calculate the repeat customer count and then percentage of repeat customer. So i have this function to calculate the overall stats for dashboard that also calculates the repeat customer percentage.

```
  async getDashboardStats(): Promise<IDashboardStats> {
      const totalCustomers = await this.customerRepository
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .getCount();

      const totalProducts = await this.productRepository
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .getCount();

      const totalOrders = await this.orderRespository
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .getCount();

      const totalPendingOrders = await this.orderRespository
        .createQueryBuilder('order')
        .where('order.status = :status', { status: OrderStatus.PENDING })
        .getCount();

      const totalDispatchedOrders = await this.orderRespository
        .createQueryBuilder('order')
        .where('order.status = :status', { status: OrderStatus.DISPATCHED })
        .getCount();

      const totalDeliveredOrders = await this.orderRespository
        .createQueryBuilder('order')
        .where('order.status = :status', { status: OrderStatus.DELIVERED })
        .getCount();

      const totalReturnedOrders = await this.orderRespository
        .createQueryBuilder('order')
        .where('order.status = :status', { status: OrderStatus.RETURNED })
        .getCount();

      const queryBuilder = this.dataSource.createQueryBuilder();

      const repeatCustomerCount = await queryBuilder
        .select('COUNT(DISTINCT customer.id)', 'repeatCustomerCount')
        .from(Order, 'o')
        .innerJoin('o.customer', 'customer')
        .groupBy('customer.id')
        .having('COUNT(o.id) > 1')
        .getRawOne();
      const repeatedCustomerPercentage =
        (Number(repeatCustomerCount?.repeatCustomerCount ?? 0) / totalCustomers) *
        100;

      const stats: IDashboardStats = {
        totalCustomers,
        totalProducts,
        totalOrders,
        totalPendingOrders,
        totalDispatchedOrders,
        totalDeliveredOrders,
        totalReturnedOrders,
        repeatedCustomerPercentage: `${repeatedCustomerPercentage.toFixed(2)}%`,
      };

      return stats;
  }
```

Problem is that, according to the details i mentioned above about the records in the tables, the `repeatCustomerCount` should be 5, and the percentage should be calculated `13.8`.

But, in debugging i found out that `repeatCustomerCount` count somehow getting count `1` that's why percentage is wrongly calculated to `2.7`.

What's wrong in the query to count repeat customer percentage?